# triangle css border scrolling on div

Tags: javascript, html, css

my problem it's with triangle css border.

You can see all it here, and for explaining well, i will put images of my problem.

What i do was: when I click on a li element, i add a class "activo", and he makes this result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XesC0.png

bassiclly, he add the triangle. But when you scrolling this, the triangle don't go along with. Like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LAGI.png

Here it's the bin: http://jsbin.com/cexevu/edit?output

Thanks

Comment: I don't have access to the jsbin code, but have you tried to add the triange within the scrollable content as a relative position to the list item? Otherwise, you will need to sync the triangle position with the scrollTop on that container using js. This won't be great as it affects performance and your fps.

Comment: I know to do in that way, but as you said, it's not the best resolution for this problmem. But thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have this CSS rule

```
.it_menuUtilizador nav .it_submenu li .activo:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
}
```

You'll want that set to relative, then you'll have to do some CSS to get it positioned where you expect it, as well as fix other problems caused by this change, then it will scroll with the rest of the page.

Comment: I tried to put has relative, and i will show to you the problem: http://i.imgur.com/GJetron.png this will put under the scroll, and my ideia its put on the front side. And the positioning i think it's some bad code, what do yout think? Thanks for your answer